# Reverse loading infinityScroll response content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if it is possible to load [infinityScroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) response content in a reverse order.

The way it is now is that you have your `index.html` that on scroll loads the external `page2.html` then `page3.html`and so on.. so when the user wants to add content he just duplicates the `pageX.html` file, changes the content and assigns the corresponding next number to the html file. Nice and simple right? But now the latest update, with the freshest content, is on the bottom of the page - not on top, as one most like would like it to be.

So my grand idea is that if the user updates the

```
<nav id="page-nav">
<a href="pageX.html"></a>
</nav>
```

to whatever the highest number of his external html file and then have infinityScroll show all the files in reverse order down to page1.html being the last one.

At the moment it works like this:
 
index.html - loads the following files in this order
 
page1.html (oldest)
page2.html
page3.html
page4.html (newest)

But I'd like it to be like this:
index.html - loads the following files in this order
 
page4.html (newest)
page3.html
page2.html
page1.html (oldest)
and whenever one adds a page it would "land on top of the stack" 


This could be pretty useful for all of us right?

Anyone up for the challenge? :)

Cheers

*actually 'infinityScroll' only reads external files from number 2 onwards, but just to present my idea clearer I use the sequence one-two-three etc..*

Comment: so you would like the user to scroll down but the page remain at the top as the latest content is placed on top? sorry but this is not very clear to me in terms of ux

Comment: see updated version..

Comment: Even before trying anything, can you identify the newest page you need to load? 
infinityScroll detects it is the last page because it gets a 404 from calling the next page, if you don't know what the last(newest) page is it would be a diferent approach.

Comment: as I mention in my question the user can identify the "newest" from the "<nav id="page-nav"><a href="pageX.html"></a></nav>". . is this what you mean?

Comment: instead of ending up with the last page being a 404 it would be "whatever-name-1.html" the number one (1) being the important so that that the user can name his files however he wants (respecting the chronological number of-course)

Comment: Being infinityScroll a gitub project, you can always change the plugin to accept a nextPage function, just changing the places where the currPage is used to validate if the function is defined.
Without changing the plugin it would be difficult to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you want to do this so you get urls that always point to the same content (permalinks), which in some cases can be very handy. For example, you know that article **foo** is located on page 5, and can then link to it with `page5.html#foo`.

You can achieve this by passing a function to the `path` option. However, you will have to know the amount of pages before hand, since that is what we use to calculate the path.

```
// Amount of pages
var numPages = 45;

// Initialize infiniteScroll plugin
$(selector).infinitescroll({
    path: function (page) {
       // Concatenate the path to a page
       var path = "page";
       // Only add a page number if page is below or equal numPages
       if (page <= numPages) {
           path += (numPages - page);
       }
       // Return path as "page%d.html"
       return path + ".html";
    }
});
```

As stated in the documentation, the path option can either be an array of URL parts (e.g. `["/page/", "/"]`) or a function that accepts the page number and returns a URL.

Comment: What I am looking for is: When the administrator want to add another page, he just makes one more html file and names it with the next corresponding number. Then this html file would be the first external html file to show up on top the page (or div), not the last after scrolling down

Comment: Just to give it an simple explanation I want to: "Reverse load infinityScroll response content"

Comment: ..so as you see there is no way of knowing the exact number of pages on beforehand. but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well, it's impossible if you don't know the exact number of pages. infiniteScroll can't magically figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the read more button at the top of the page, make an [event listener](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll):

```
$('.selector').infinitescroll({
    loading: {
        finished: function(){
         //move your newly-added content to the top using $.prepend()
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample in which new element(which you need to add) will add on top in the container element.

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="container">   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 100px;
    width:500px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY

```
// page count
var count = 0;
var content_to_add_on_top = '<div>Page {count}</div>';


// call this function in every 2 seconds
setInterval(function () {

    // code which you need to call when you wants to add an element to top in container
    var content = content_to_add_on_top;
    content = content.replace(/{count}/g, count);
    var container = $('#container');
    var child_elements = container.children();
    if (child_elements.length === 0) {
        // if child element does not exists
        container.append(content);
    } else {
        // if child exists
        var first_element = child_elements[0];
        $(first_element).prepend(content);
    }
    // increment count
    count++;
}, 2000);
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/HTYga/)

Hope it helps.